# How can i set PrintPriviewDialog papersize to a5 in c# codebehind?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

i have a windows forms application , with a simple windows form that contains a pannel .
I have set the panel size to :560, 579 in pixels
 and I have set the print document size this way :

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize a = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A5 (148 x 210 mm)", 584, 827);
printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = a;
```

now I want the printpreviewdialoge page size to be a5 or at least the same size as my print document and fit it , how can i acheive that ?

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pnlPrint.Width, pnlPrint.Height);
        pnlPrint.DrawToBitmap(b, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, pnlPrint.Width, pnlPrint.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(b,0,0);
    }

    private void Print()
    {
    PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    var paperSize = printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.PaperName == "A5");
    printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize; 
    printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get the A5 `PaperSize` object from the `PrinterSettings` property on the `PrintDocument` object.  It has a `PaperSizes` property that holds all the paper sizes for the selected printer.  You can use LINQ to find the one you want.  For example:

```
var paperSize = printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.PaperName == "A5");
printDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```

Comment: well thanks but I steel have the problem ! that the printpriviewdialoge does not fit to my panel which I have drawn it to bit map :( I added my complete code , the printpriviewdialoge is steel a4

Comment: my pannel is at the top corner of the print priview and the rest is white , I want the rest to fit to my panel image

Comment: Okay, it's unclear what you're asking.  Do you want the paper size to be something specific, or do you want the print preview dialog to be a certain size?

Comment: I want the print preview dialog to be a5 size and I want the image to fit the printpreview dialog , is it clear ?

Comment: You want the dialog to be of a5 size, on the screen?  I don't really think that's what you want.  But, you can set the size of the dialog with the `PrintDialog.ClientSize` property and set it's location with the `PrintDialog.Location` property.

Comment: I exactly want that , how about with printpriviewdialog ? what you say is with printdialog not with printpreviewdialog

Comment: Sorry, that should have been " `PrintPreviewDialog.ClientSize` property and set it's location with the `PrintPreviewDialog.Location`..."

Comment: I set that this way : printPreviewDialog1.ClientSize=new Size(200, 300);   but again the page is in A4 size and does not change

Comment: The size of a window/dialog is in pixels, 200x300 pixels is not likely to be A4 size.

Answer (score 1):

Just check my answer from the link below :

[Printing Envelopes from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751578/printing-envelopes-from-c-sharp/28346590#28346590)

Thank you.